# What package provides keyval.sty

Tags: xkeyval, minimal

I am setting up a very minimal and custom texlive environment. So, I started with a minimal install and I am adding packages as I need them.

When I try to compile my current document, it reports a missing keyval.sty. What package provides this? I have tried xkeyval, ltxkeys, fontspec, etc. But still it produces the same error.

Comment: Part of the LaTeX core (its in `graphics` in the LaTeX distributuion).

Comment: keyval is in the _required_ section of the core latex distribution (in required/graphics) but any distribution should include it if it includes latex at all.

Comment: Any updates? If you need still help, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @boby Nothing much to update except that I installed several core packages and tyat solved the problem.